# Scrapy-Splash running Tor Proxy

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I try to build proxy settings of splash. Here I assign Tor or Polipo port address to `set_proxy`, but it doesn't work. I get 504 error:

```
 function main(splash)
            local host = "localhost"
            local port = 8123
            --local type = "SOCKS5"

            splash:on_request(function (request)
               request:set_proxy{host, port}
        end)

        splash:go(splash.args.url)
        splash:wait(0.5)
        local image = assert(splash:png{render_all=true})
        return {png=image}
    end
    """

    url = 'https://www.torproject.org/'
```

In polipo.config(9150 is tor port):

```
socksParentProxy = localhost:9150
diskCacheRoot=""
#socksProxyType = socks5
```

In settings.py:

```
HTTP_PROXY = 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'thefork.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'thefork.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
```

How can I fix this, or is there an easier way to use splash with Tor?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue trying to get splash working with other proxy servers. I think it is a problem with scrapy splash and not splash itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I believe is in the middleware you have installed. Try setting the proxy manually on every request. This is how I solved my issue. It tries to proxy every request and when you send a request to splash it attempts to go to your localhost through the proxy and fails.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you implemented this solution?

Comment: The solution is to not use Splash. Splash in my opinion is very specific use cases. Nobody wants to write a LUA script to do some basic logic in their spider. I only use Splash when Javascript is necessary to be rendered and can't be gotten another way. Also, only use Splash when you dont need to interact with web elements but need the reduced footprint of Splash. Other than that use Scrapy and Selenium.